# Most succinct if(last_item) in `for..in` loop

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

In templating languages like Liquid, you can use `forloop.last` to find if the current iteration in a for loop is the last iteration.

Is there something similar available for Swift? What is the most succinct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Call `enumerate()` on the thing being enumerated to get a tuple of index number and value. Now you can check the index number to see which one you're processing now.

```
let arr = ["hey", "ha", "ho"]
for (ix,what) in arr.enumerate() {
    print(what)
    if ix == arr.count-1 {
        print("that was the last one")
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrific! Tx! In Swift 5, it's now called "enumerated" with a d at the en(d).

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can get what you want with `for let x in xs.dropLast()` and then handling the last one specially.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that this is not always possible: the "thing" on the right-hand of the `in` keyword is a value conforming to the `SequenceType`. This might be some "finite" container, where the number of elements are defined (as @matt used in his answer). But it might also be a sequence with unlimited number of elements, or a container where the number of elements is not defined. Then, there's no way to determine the last element.

Comment: Upvote pending if you can offer examples of infinite arrays or where the number of elements cannot be determined.

Comment: @ZoffDino Sequences are not just arrays (which have a `count` method returning the number of elements). An example for an unlimited sequence is one that has a generator which produces prime numbers. As far as I know, there is no max prime number ;)  Or, take a random number generator, a recurring bit pattern generator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking something like this? I am using xCode7

```
var arr = ["cooper","ant","Yolo"]


for i in arr
{
   if i == arr.last
   {
        print("Win")
    }
}
```

i used `array.last` where it is a function an array has and you can return the last element of the array.